# SQLITE_CORRUPT problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Recently I implemented a cache component in my iPhone app, that uses SQLite.
I'm writing and reading the data natively w/o any wrapper framework.
The problem is that after using the app for a while it's beginning to get SQLITE_CORRUPT status code in response to a any SQL statement I perform in the DB.

I'm using SQLiteManager as my DB mgmt tool. When the DB becomes corrupted I'm trying to analyze and inspect via the SQLiteManager but it doesn't even allow me to browse through the data in the table and just outputs a laconic message that says data is corrupted.

Anyone can assist with this one ? First of all - How the hell the DB gets to that situation and second - how or where can I see the data anyway ?

Thanks,
Guy.

Comment: You're going to have to post the code you have that handles the caching if you want anyone to be able to help you.

But, is there a good reason not to use NSUserDefaults for what you're doing? Or even just maintaining a plist file in the app's docs directory? Don't know what you mean by "cache component", but sql is a pain to use unless you really have to (and when you have to, I'd use Core Data instead of directly dealing with the SQL).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CharlieMezak. plist and NSUserDefaults aren't good enough for me because I need a more complex mechanism than just saving key\value entries. I examined Core Data but I don't really need to model my entities and implement O\R mapping, so it also doesn't fit. I'm left only with native SQL...

Comment: You might not need some features of Core Data, but at least you won't have to worry about futzing around with SQL directly. I'd skip right past an SQL wrapper and go straight to core data. It's clean, it's simple, and it has those higher-level features if you ever find that you need them.

Comment: I did some refactoring to the existing code in my app. If that doesn't straight things up - I'll migrate to Core Data.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q21). Here they have mentioned there are very few chances for db to be corrupted.

They have also list out the [chances](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseCorruption) how DB can be corrupted. And from there refer following example which can cause the problem to the db.

```
  CREATE TABLE ex1(a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b);
  INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES(1,2);
  INSERT INTO ex1 VALUES(2,3);
  CREATE TRIGGER ex1_tr1 AFTER UPDATE ON ex1 BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ex1 WHERE a=old.b;
  END;

  UPDATE ex1 SET b=b+1;
```

In the example above, the first cycle of the UPDATE causes the trigger to fire and delete the second row of the ex1 table. When the second cycle of the UPDATE loop runs, it attempts to process the second row of the ex1 table. SQLite recognized that the second row had been deleted so it aborts the second cycle, but it was failing to clean up after itself properly which could lead to database corruption on subsequent cycles of the loop.

**So, Basically you need to find out the situation where this has happened in your code, By debugging or by following steps through your application or any other mechanism.**

Comment: Thanks for the reference ! Looked at the link and found that REPLACE INTO clause can cause corruption.. I'm replacing the REPLACE with "primitive" update and insert. Will update if that worked.

Comment: @Guys My pleasure. Would be glad if it works for you. And if it does accept the answer or upvote the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Guys Have you found the solution for sqlite corruption.
coz am too facing this issue.